# SSIS: recordset or temp table

Tags: ssis, recordset

I have an SSIS application that needs to get data from 2 databases of different servers (not link). I need to get the match names and DOB records between 2 database then use the results to insert/update a table.
My initial approach is to use OLE DB source then Merge Join and put the results to recordset. Then on controlflow, use the results of the recordset to insert/update a table. But I can't see the recordset at the control flow. 
Alternative solution is to create temp tables. But the temp tables are not visible since they reside at the tempdb database of each servers.
What is a better approach for this problem?

Comment: Data on server A and Server B. Is one set of tables a driver and the other a reference or do both sets need to be merged and loaded into a final destination?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would keep a database around for work table or create a schema for those work tables.

Next, add a SQL control flow task that truncates the table that will hold the intermediate result. After this, load the intermediate result set into the table, do the operation and optionally, truncate the table again.

The recordset destination is fine for smaller datasets. But if you plan to use it for larger datasets that dont fit memory it will be very slow.

If you dont have a database/schema that can serve as a workspace, you could use RAW files to hold the intermediate result. Those are very fast too.

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by `put the results to recordset`?

If you join two sources on the data flow using a join, that "recordset" on the join will only be available during the current dataflow. You cant use it on the control flow after the data flow is finisehd.

why cant you just insert the resultset on the destination DB? You can perform any other transform operation on the same data flow and insert the result on the destination database.

Or, if you really need to do something that can only be done on the control flow before insert the data, you can yes, insert the recordset on a temp table on the destination using a oleDBDestination and access in on another dataflow (not a very good approach, though)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used an OLE DB destination then create another package to update the rest of the tables using OLD DB Command.